# what does pulp.value(x) return PulpPython

Tags: pulp

iam trying to display a list of items but im facing a problem with the function pulp.value() it's not working and i didn't know where does the probleme come from if someone can help me please

my lists:

```
exams={'Exam PL':30,
    'Exam Graphe':30,
    'Exam Angular':60,
    'Exam English':90,
    'Frensh Exam':60,}

    slots=[('A',0,30),('A',30,60),
    ('A',90,60),('B',0,30),
    ('B',30,90),('B',120,30),
    ('C',0,90),('C',90,60),]

assign={(exam,slot):pulp.LpVariable('%r in slot %r'%(exam,slot),cat=pulp.LpBinary) for exam in exams for slot in slots}
```

the assign function :

```
for slot in slots:
problem.addConstraint
(sum(assign[(exam,slot)]
for exam in exams)<= 1)
```

my loop to display:

```
     print('Exam assignement:')
     print('-'*72)
     for(exam,slot),assigned in sorted(assign.items()):
       if pulp.value(assigned):
          print('Exam %r assigned to Slot %r' %(exam,slot))
     print('')
```

the if condition is not working i didn't know why in the example where i took it from it's working fine

Comment: are you ever calling the solve function?

Comment: are you able to provide a Minimum, complete and verifiable example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)